# Unable to parse a product title and it's price from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch product title and it's price from a webpage but every time when I run my script I get this error `` instead of the content. I checked out page source where the selectors I've used within my script are there.

[Site link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DOLQ0BY)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DOLQ0BY'

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
product_price = soup.select_one("[id='priceblock_ourprice']").text
print(product_name,product_price)
```

How can I get the product name and it's price from aforementioned site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the header to the one the server expects

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}

res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DOLQ0BY/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
product_price = soup.select_one("[id='priceblock_ourprice']").text
print(product_name,product_price)
```

---

For different products you will need to find a selector that is common across all asins. For the two supplied you can use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0'}

asins = ['B013TCZVVS','B01DOLQ0BY']

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    for asin in asins:
        res = s.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
        product_price = soup.select_one(".comparison_baseitem_column .a-offscreen").text
        print(product_name,product_price)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. However, I get the same error when I try using this `https://www.amazon.com/dp/B013TCZVVS/`. The quoted link also has the same headers.

Comment: [id='priceblock_ourprice'] doesn't work for your second url. Add additional header of user-agent and you will see

Comment: Error thrown at the `product_name` line. I'll try adding some more headers to see how it behaves.

Comment: See edit above. You will need to inspect across different asins

Answer (score 0):

Instead of res.text try res.body

Also as a debugging technique, print the request's response. That will help you see what data is being returnd from the request with your current config.